# External Script breaks Angular 7 navigation

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a standard Angular 7 site with lazy loading in place. The app is in PROD without any issues. Now I'm integrating an external script which loads a chatbot on the site. According to their documentation I only have to add a piece of HTML within the HEAD tag and all should work. The thing is the chat itself works however the angular navigation is broken in terms of having to click twice to an item in the navbar to actual go to the desired route (although when you first click the URL changes). It's weird and I have never come across this before so I was wondering whether Angular exposes any kind of special debugging or something like that for the routing process - note that I have `enableTracing` set to true and according to those logs the apps works fine but like I said, the view is rendered when you click on the second time as well as the styles applied to things like `routerLinkActive` etc.

Any ideas of what could be going on? I don't know how the JS file could be interacting with the actual Angular routing process.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: you should include your chatbot script in the `index.html` and it should be good.

Comment: That’s where it is and it makes the application behaving wrongly. As I said the chatbot appears and works but the Angular navigation is impacted by the script somehow and it breaks